# Using custom Qt class in Scroll Area and forcing not to resize elements but scroll bar to appear

Tags: c++, qt

I tried to solve this problem for couple of days but I made no progress, I think I'm missing something, please help me to solve it.

In mainwindow I created scroll area and gave it vertical layout. I have created Qt Designer Class (myform.h, myform.cpp and myform.ui) and put some buttons + vertical layout.

This is "myform.ui":  http://oi59.tinypic.com/23sch2r.jpg

I want the scroll area in mainwindow contain "myform.ui", and elements in "myform.ui" would not be resized but scroll bars appear instead in scroll area.

My mainwindow.cpp is

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "myform.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    MyForm* myform = new MyForm(this);
    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    layout->addWidget(myform);

    ui->scrollArea->setWidgetResizable(false);
    ui->scrollArea->setLayout(layout);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

The problem is that Scroll bars does not appear and the elements are being resized upon resizing window.

Picture: http://oi62.tinypic.com/w83xvp.jpg

This is just a minimal example to illustrate the problem I am having.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation for [QScrollArea](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qscrollarea.html#details), it looks like you have to set the background widget into the scrolling area. This code is taken directly from the documentation of the `QScrollArea` widget:

```
QLabel *imageLabel = new QLabel;
QImage image("happyguy.png");
imageLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));

scrollArea = new QScrollArea;
scrollArea->setBackgroundRole(QPalette::Dark);
scrollArea->setWidget(imageLabel);
```

An image label is made. A pixmap is loaded into it. Then the scroll area widget is dictated by the `setWidget()` command.

In your code, I think that `ui->scrollArea->setLayout(layout);`

should be

`ui->scrollArea->setWidget(layout);` instead.

**Note:** I have not tested this code but think it will solve your problem.